# SSRS deployment error

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I am geting the error message:

Could not connect to the report server "xyz" Verify that the targetserverurl is valid and that you have the correct permission to connect to the report server.

Addition information:
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. (System.Web.Services)

Comment: Make sure that in the reporting services configuration manager, the service is started. Then, in SSDT, rt. click on your project, click on properties, and under configuration properties in general , check if the target server url is valid. Try to browse the url. Also see, that the account you are logged in with, has sufficient permission to access the url.

Comment: The service is started and is running. I am able to browse the target server URL just fine through a web browser.

Comment: Still waiting for more answers please.

Comment: Are you certain your ReportServer URL is valid?  When deploying, the target server URL should typically end in "/ReportServer/" and not "/Reports/", unless you've changed the default configurations.  

Can you tell us more about your configuration?  Is this a scaled-out environment with multiple nodes?  Is there anything non-traditional about it?

Are you seeing anything in the SSRS logs to indicate that you're even connecting to the server? (.../ReportServer/LogFiles/)

Comment: My server URL is correct, there is nothing un-traditional about my configuration. This same project was used almost every 2 weeks for new deployments when i make changes to it. and now out of a sudden i am getting this error message I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

-In BIDS, click the "Project" menu >  Properties...
-For the TargetServerURL, specify the full URL http:///ReportServer
-Make up a folder name for the "TargetReportForlder" field and click OK
-Try deploying again